# MongoDB - slow updates with random intervals

Tags: mongodb

I have same collection with a lot of updates going against records, but in about 10% of the cases update takes a lot longer than it should - anywhere between 40ms to 6 or more seconds, which is not normal.

All the updates are upserts, are addressed by _id, has only one $inc with multiple fields (almost always the same, and this seems to have no impact), the $inc is against fields in root level and write_concern is "0".

This affects more than one collection. Most updates however happens against a relatively small collection with just 96,000 records, although there is collections with more than 40 million records.

Topography is 1 master 1 replica. The network also does not seem to be an issue.

Any ideas, how to even debug this?

Comment: Is this running on infrastructure you have control over, i.e. not a small VM instance where they throttle or limit your cpu cylcles?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne both master and slave are running on dedicated servers and are not even close to reaching any cpu, memory or IO limits. All of them run on SSD's with some sort of RAID config, however, I am not aware what kind of RAID is used.

Comment: Sorry, but - your own hardware?  Not VM's?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne that's correct.

Comment: Please be careful regarding the terminology. Are we talking of  a [master/slave](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/) or a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) replication? Furthermore, are we talking of dedicated machines or are there other services running? Please describe the storage technology, used filesystem etc.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg sorry - I am less sysadmin, more developer. It is a replica set setup, one primary server and a replica, both on separate servers. Updates are against primary. Besides mongodb, there is nothing else except standard OS services running. Mongo version is 3.0.3 with wiredtiger, ona XFS file system.